# How to convert _JsonMap to object in flutter / dart

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have the following class:

```
@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true)
class Section {
  @JsonKey(name: '_id')
  late String id;
  late BaseInfo info;
  @JsonKey(name: 'document_ids')
  late List<String>? documentIds;
  late List<String>? tags;
  late List<Comment>? comments;
  late List<UserBasedPermission>? permissions;

  Section();

  factory Section.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$SectionFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$SectionToJson(this);
}
```

Now when I try to call fromJson I get the error message that a `Map<String, dynamic>` was expected but a `_JsonMap` was found.
The code I use to convert it is as follows:

```
String test = '{"_id":"610b8ce9faa3695a81b93e98","info":{"name":"Mathematik","description":"Alles was mit Mathe zu tun hat Hurz ein Reh. Ein Hirsch 222 3333 444 555","active":false,"created_date":1628146903325,"created_by":"admin","last_update":null,"last_update_by":null,"last_comment":null,"deletion_date":null,"deleted_by":null,"locked_by":null,"locked_date":null,"object_type":"SECTION","version":6,"api_version":1},"document_ids":[],"tags":["mathematik","mathe","wissenschaft"],"comments":[{"user":"","timestamp":1628579634126,"comment":"Das ist ein Kommentar"},{"user":"admin","timestamp":1628580529698,"comment":"Noch ein Kommentar"}],"permissions":{"read_write_users":null,"read_only_users":null,"excluded_users":null}}';
        Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson = jsonDecode(test);
        print("parsedJson type: ${parsedJson.runtimeType} / $parsedJson");
        Section sec = Section.fromJson(parsedJson);
```

I just can't figure out where the problem is here.

Comment: Does anything change when you write `Section.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic>.from(parsedJson));`?

Comment: No unfortunately, the error is still the same

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the variable this way:

```dart
 Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson = jsonDecode(test) as Map<String,dynamic>;
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help. I still get the error "Expected a value of type 'List<dynamic>?' but got one of '_JsonMap'

Comment: On what line is the error exactly ?

Comment: The error occurs here `Section sec = Section.fromJson(parsedJson);`

Comment: The output of the `print` line before that works fine: `parsedJson type: _JsonMap / {_id: 610b8ce9faa3695a81b93e98, info: {name: Mathematik, description: Alles ...`

Comment: Try this `Section.fromJson(parsedJson as Map<String,dynamic>);`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there was some problem in the JsonSerializable annotation. After I changed it to `@JsonSerializable(explicitToJson: true, includeIfNull: true, anyMap: false)` it works as expected.